# single op amp (NE5532) un-balanced to balanced

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]
a long time ago I saw a cct using a single op amp (NE5532) to convert un-balanced to balanced lines, it had splt rails where its output pin was grounded and the rails became the output. i.e. because the output was grounded the rail pins shifted creating the balanced output. Anyone familiar with this design and where can I find it.

see attached

Thanks guys.

Comment: sorry guys, PIN 1 to ground.

Comment: Are you sure? NE5532 is a dual op amp. What signal level are you working with?

Comment: Balanced but offset DC.. Why not use unity gain +1, -1 with dual OA's?

Comment: Thanks Tony, but part of the objective was to do it with a single ne5532 op amp stage.

Comment: Yes ne5532 is a dual op amp

Comment: Audio level  will typically be dbu dbm. .775v or 1v approx. Not critical.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen what you asked for but think this is better.

[image]

Notice I edited/ corrected the CM input range for this after copying from datasheet which used a single supply.

[image]